# help with rewriterules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need help rewriting

```
online.php to -> /users/online
```

and

```
profile.php?id=3426 to -> /users/3426
```

and

```
users.php to -> /users
```

Would this be possible?

And is there any good mod_rewrite cheat sheets out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the rules to get you started, I've assumed you want the visitor to see "users/online/" but actually deliver the content from online.php.

Because you are using the "users/" pseudo address for each of these, it is reasonably important what order you place the rules in.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^users/ users.php [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^users/online/ online.php [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^users/([^/\.]+)/?$ profile.php?Page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```